# 'String' module object has no attribute 'join'

Tags: python, string, textbox, pygame

So, I want to create a user text input box in Pygame, and I was told to look at a class module called inputbox. So I downloaded inputbox.py and imported into my main game file. I then ran a function inside it and got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dennis\Tournament\inputbox.py", line 64, in <module>
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
 File "C:\Users\Dennis\Tournament\inputbox.py", line 62, in main
print(ask(screen, "Name") + " was entered")
 File "C:\Users\Dennis\Tournament\inputbox.py", line 46, in ask
display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'join'
```

I tried running the inputbox.py while on it's own and got the same error.
I am using Python 3.3 and Pygame 3.3 so that could be an issue. I was told that many 'string' functions have been removed lately. If anyone knows what the problem is and can fix it, then here is the code:
I would be truly grateful if anyone can fix the problem as I've been trying to set up user inputs in my Pygame games for a long time now. 
Thanks a lot for the answers in advance.

```
# by Timothy Downs, inputbox written for my map editor

# This program needs a little cleaning up
# It ignores the shift key
# And, for reasons of my own, this program converts "-" to "_"

# A program to get user input, allowing backspace etc
# shown in a box in the middle of the screen
# Called by:
# import inputbox
# answer = inputbox.ask(screen, "Your name")
#
# Only near the center of the screen is blitted to

import pygame, pygame.font, pygame.event, pygame.draw, string
from pygame.locals import *

def get_key():
  while 1:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
      return event.key
    else:
      pass

def display_box(screen, message):
  "Print a message in a box in the middle of the screen"
  fontobject = pygame.font.Font(None,18)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10,
                    200,20), 0)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),
                   ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 102,
                    (screen.get_height() / 2) - 12,
                    204,24), 1)
  if len(message) != 0:
    screen.blit(fontobject.render(message, 1, (255,255,255)),
                ((screen.get_width() / 2) - 100, (screen.get_height() / 2) - 10))
  pygame.display.flip()

def ask(screen, question):
  "ask(screen, question) -> answer"
  pygame.font.init()
  current_string = []
  display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  while 1:
    inkey = get_key()
    if inkey == K_BACKSPACE:
      current_string = current_string[0:-1]
    elif inkey == K_RETURN:
      break
    elif inkey == K_MINUS:
      current_string.append("_")
    elif inkey <= 127:
      current_string.append(chr(inkey))
    display_box(screen, question + ": " + string.join(current_string,""))
  return string.join(current_string,"")

def main():
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,240))
  print(ask(screen, "Name") + " was entered")

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: I hope someone that knows how to solve this see's it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to use the join method from the string module when you should be using it from the str object.

```
string.join(current_string,"")
```

that line for example should be

```
"".join(current_string)
```

where current_string is an iteratible.

Just a quick example on how the .join method works

```
", ".join(['a','b','c'])
```

will give you a str object of the letters a b and c separated by a comma and a space.

Comment: PERFECT!!! I tried current_string.join(""), and it never work so I gave up. And I was about try that and just never bothered. Now I can't believe I wasted so much of my time. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

`string.join(words[, sep])` [has been deprecated with `Python 2.4`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/node111.html), removed completely with `Python 3.0`

So up to `Python 2.7` one could both used `string.join(words[, sep])` and `sep.join(words)` (although the first was not recommended since `Python 2.4`), and from `Python 3.0` only the latter is available.