# attribute error and key error in the join operation of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a function given as follows

```
# Transform a list of word ids into a caption.
    def ids2caption(self, caption_ids):
        id2word = self.vocabulary['id2word']
        return string.join([id2word[w] for w in caption_ids], " ")
```

It will cause the following error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-246a65714ebe> in <module>
     69 print('imgId', imgId)
     70 print('caption', caption.tolist())
---> 71 print('captionString', trainData.ids2caption(caption))

<ipython-input-22-246a65714ebe> in ids2caption(self, caption_ids)
     45     def ids2caption(self, caption_ids):
     46         id2word = self.vocabulary['id2word']
---> 47         return string.join([id2word[w] for w in caption_ids], " ")
     

AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'join'
```

I changed its implementation to the following ones, and I got some other error messages.

```
# Transform a list of word ids into a caption.
def ids2caption(self, caption_ids):
    id2word = self.vocabulary['id2word']
    return "".join([id2word[w] for w in caption_ids])


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-0f32ccd7d847> in <module>
     69 print('imgId', imgId)
     70 print('caption', caption.tolist())
---> 71 print('captionString', trainData.ids2caption(caption))

<ipython-input-23-0f32ccd7d847> in ids2caption(self, caption_ids)
     46         id2word = self.vocabulary['id2word']
     47         #return string.join([id2word[w] for w in caption_ids], " ")
---> 48         return "".join([id2word[w] for w in caption_ids])
     49 
     50     # Return imgId, and a random caption for that image.

<ipython-input-23-0f32ccd7d847> in <listcomp>(.0)
     46         id2word = self.vocabulary['id2word']
     47         #return string.join([id2word[w] for w in caption_ids], " ")
---> 48         return "".join([id2word[w] for w in caption_ids])
     49 
     50     # Return imgId, and a random caption for that image.

KeyError: tensor(5001)
```

Comment: Did you try a) printing `[id2word[w] for w in caption_ids]` because you’ll probably get the same error, or b) changing that line to something more defensive e.g. `return "".join([id2word.get(w,”UNKNOWN WORD”) for w in caption_ids])`. Given you haven’t defended against `w` not being a key in `id2word` why are you surprised by the error? If you don’t attempt debugging you’re only going to have to ask question here.

Comment: Just as the error messages say, module `string` does not have the attribute `join` and object `id2word`, wherever it is, does not have the key `w`, whatever it is. Why are you surprised?

Comment: Simple key `tensor(5001)` doesn't exist in dictionary `id2word`

Comment: You can check a seem problem like you here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451942/string-module-object-has-no-attribute-join>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn’t attempt to not fail if `w` isn’t a key in `id2word`, so it shouldn’t be too much of a surprise when it does fail. You could try changing

```
return "".join([id2word[w] for w in caption_ids])
```

To

```
return "".join([id2word.get(w,”UNKNOWN WORD”) for w in caption_ids])
```

Or even:

```
return "".join([id2word.get(w,w) for w in caption_ids])
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `join` is

```
delimiter.join(iterable)
```

`string` is the name of a module, not a delimiter string. You seem to want to use a space as the delimiter, so it should be:

```
" ".join([id2word[w] for w in caption_ids])
```